# Changes in multiple splits at the same time

Tags: bash, vim, vi

I generally work in vim with 3 or 4 splits. I am looking for shortcuts to do things like `set number`, `set list`, `set nolist` etc in all the splits. Can one suggest some elegant method to do this instead of setting it in all splits one by one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
:windo set nonumber list
```

and more commands you can add to the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can set them in `vimrc` just as you would do it from inside the editor. Mine is under `/etc/vim/vimrc`. This way, every time you open your editor the settings will be there.

Comment: You should stay away from editing the system `vimrc` file. It would be better to edit your own personal `vimrc` usually found at `~/.vimrc`.  Please see `:h vimrc-intro` and `:h vimrc` for more information.